# JavaFX setting selection in a TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx

How do I set a selection in a TableView? I want the first index selected by default.

```
productTable.selectionModelProperty().set(value);
```

Is this right? What should `value` be?

Comment: I think that this question is duplicated with these [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639386/select-row-in-javafx-tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639386/select-row-in-javafx-tableview)

Comment: I think that the question is duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413419/javafx-2-how-to-focus-a-table-row-programmatically

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `TableViewSelectionModel` provides various methods of selections:

```
productTable.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

Even the default value should be selected by someone in somewhere. In your case, it is you ;), running above code in some init block.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, `TableViewSelectionModel.select(int index)` or, if you don't have the index, but you do have the object you want to select handy, `TableViewSelectionModel.select(T object)`. Docs [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html#select(int)).

Comment: I know this is somewhat an old question now, however does there exist a way of doing this for multiple selections? Analogous to say `TableViewSelectionModel.select(ObservableList<T> objects>)`?

Comment: @swshaun It seems like a strange omission, but I don't see anything to that effect.